# Delete repeated and unused CSS in style file in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have a CSS style file, that have 13000 lines code, because I help from some different template site.

How can I delete repeated and unused CSS from that file, in Microsoft Visual Studio?

[image]

Comment: It's **CSS** - not "CCS" ....

Comment: @marc-3 sorry for my mistake